# How to obtain envelope equation for oscillating functon?

Tags: real-analysis

Some oscillating function is given. How can I obtain its envelope? For example, for $ \sin x$ I should get $\pm 1$.

Particularly, I am interested in envelope for  $$\begin{equation}\frac{(1-x \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}{\left(1-x \cot (2 \kappa a x)-x^{2} / 2\right)^{2}+x^{2}(1-(x / 2) \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}\end{equation}$$

UPD
by envelope I mean line which lies over maximum of function, for instance
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnADl.png)

Comment: Could you define "envelope"?

Comment: In your example a good "envelope" appear to be  $4(1+x^2)/Q $ with  $Q=2+2x^2+x^4-\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+16x^2}$.

Comment: Is the "envelope" uniquely defined for any given function? If not, what characteristics are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maxima are at the poles of the cotangent, so for an envelope just retain only the cotangents
$$\frac{(1-x \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}{\left(1-x \cot (2 \kappa a x)-x^{2} / 2\right)^{2}+x^{2}(1-(x / 2) \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}\mapsto
\frac{(x \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}{\left(x \cot (2 \kappa a x)\right)^{2}+x^{2}((x / 2) \cot (2 \kappa a x))^{2}}=\frac{1}{1+x^2/4}.$$

Here is a comparison for $\kappa a=1$.

[image]